# Vue3 Pinia action is not being called

Tags: vuejs3, apollo-client, state-management, vue-apollo, pinia

I am trying to setup a store using Pinia in vue3 with apollo client and composition API.

here is my store

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import apolloClient from "../apollo.provider";
import { ALL_POSTS } from '@/constants/blog'

export const usePostsStore = defineStore("posts", {
  state: () => ({
    posts: []
  }),

  actions: {
    async AllPosts() {
      const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
        query: ALL_POSTS,
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
      })
      console.log(data)
      this.posts = data.posts.data
    },
  },

})
```

and here is the response

```
{
  "data": {
    "posts": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 5
        },
        {
          "id": 4
        },
        {
          "id": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get an empty array with this setup. Please help me understand how to get the posts!

Comment: To debug, don't destructure the response. You should set  `const response = await apolloClient.query...` and then `console.log(response)` to see what you get first

Comment: My Pinia global setup works as I use store for auth and I can use it to query user too with similar store setup shown in question. But for some reason in posts store my action does not return anything. Console log returns nothing. and my console is clean with no errors or warnings. Vue dev tools shows an empty array posts: []
Im still not sure how to debug this problem!

Comment: So you need to find out if your action is called or not. Add a console log at the beginning of your action

Comment: If I add some static items in post state array I can see them in the console but how can I see if my action is called?

Comment: `async AllPosts() { console.log('called') }` Just add a console log in it

Comment: I assume you talk about the actions: {} itself. Ive tried console log but as explained nothing is returned.

Comment: So it is not get called?

Comment: Appearantly not, but this is streght forward setup used in my auth store. Everything works there, I can query user. But in posts store Its never called!

Comment: So you should focus on why your action is not got called rather than how to use Apollo Client, right?

Comment: That's right. But there are no errors produced. How to debug such a type of problem?

Comment: The way to debug is you need to understand everything. You should know what the scenario of your code is. Let's say your code start from A -> B -> C -> D -> E. Don't just focus on E. You need to make sure all the breakpoints work. Add a console log or debugger to A, B, C, D, and E to see which step is not working.